# Bidirectionally of the "Tangent Criterion"

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, angle, tangent-line

I've recently been reviewing some basic geometry concepts when I saw this one in Evan Chen's fantastic "[Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads](http://web.evanchen.cc/geombook.html)" (EGMO).

[image]

Proving $(i)\Rightarrow (iii)$ is quite simple.

> **Hint**: Move point $C$ in the circumcircle so that $\angle BAC=90°$

Nevertheless, I've had some issues trying to prove that this proposition is [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional), i.e. $(i)\iff (iii)$.

Since one of the directions is already proven, I only need to show $(iii)\Rightarrow (i)$

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the solution is

> Move point $C$ in the circumcircle so that $\angle ABC=90°$.

Comment: I can't believe I was so stupid I didn't see it! +1

Comment: Well, you did all the work :D